# Possible nuance in meaning of 'the first thing to observe'

Tags: phrase-meaning

Phrases such as 'the first thing to observe', where the verb 'observe' could be replaced by other verbs, are frequently seen in English sentences, for example in

> The first thing to observe is that both of these equations have a coefficient of 1 in front of the x.

Now, what is meant by that phrase?

> 1. The first thing that can be observed
> 2. The first thing that should be observed

Does its exact meaning depend on the context in which it appears?

Answer (score 0):

Have you done some research into infinitives? Infinitives are usually formed with **to** + a **verb**.

> The first thing **to observe**, what does it mean?

In this context, it means **the first thing that should be observed**.

> The first thing that should be observed is that both of these equations have a coefficient of 1 in front of the x.

However, it may not always mean that. Context can be modified and the meaning will change with it.
If you wanted to say **The first thing that should be observed** you would use **to be observed**.

> The first star in the sky **to be observed** is one that is not in our galaxy.

Comment: I'm familiar with the syntax used here. My question is about its meaning.

Comment: I was just making sure you were familiar with the technical terms, but I also answered your questions regarding the meaning.

Comment: In the specific example you used, the author is using it as a way to guide the teaching he wants to do, so it's like your interpretation #2.  I'd translate it as, "The first thing that you the reader should observe is [this] because it's the first thing that I'm going to write about."

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to observe is that the room is painted pink.

This means: 
The first thing [the reader or listener should observe or anyone in fact] is that the room is pink.

The first thing to see when you go to Paris is the Eiffel Tower.

It is usually spoken but can also be written. This pattern is "instructional". It implies someone is giving advice to someone else about something.

The first thing to do is read the question carefully.

Advice to question readers, for example.

By using this pattern, one can avoid directly addressing someone while still dispensing advice or giving an order.

Answer (score 0):

> The first thing to observe...

is kind of a teaching or explaining cliché.  It's somewhat close to your suggestion of "the first thing that should be observed," but, to me, it doesn't carry a particularly strong connotation of "should" - i.e., the suggestion that you are supposed to do something. Rather, it's more of a statement that there's something that probably stands out or is most obvious or important about the situation, and is therefore the first thing that the explainer will discuss.

There might be some implication that the listener would be intelligent to have understood why this particular thing stands out.